# Where to register REST route to wordpress plugin endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, routes, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

Where must the registration function go? (`register_rest_route()`)

- Must it be in theme/child functions.php?
- Or can it be in the plugin base php file? (e.g. \wp-content\plugins\example\example.php)

Is there any documentation that clarifies this?

It is not mentioned in the official documentation at:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/

Similarly, where must the endpoint function be stored? The registration function only names it, without specifying its path.

For example, can you do like this:

- Registration function call (`register_rest_route`) goes in main plugin file (e.g. \wp-content\plugins\example\example.php)
- Endpoint function is in some other plugin file (e.g. \wp-content\plugins\example\sub-path-stuff\example-controller.php)

If so, how?

The following link appears to attempt this but does not specify these attributes (e.g. \wp-content\plugins\example\example.php)

Comment: Everything that Jonny Tee says is correct, I just wanted to clarify some things. In WordPress each plugin and theme gets one and only one "boot up file". For a plugin, it is the one with the PHP header comments, and for a theme it is functions.php. You can put any and all functions directly in these files, WordPress will `include` them, and PHP will put the functions into the global namespace. Ideally, however, these files will further `require_once` other files so that you can split your code, PHP will follow the same logic and you'll save some sanity.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So In that case I'll plan to create a registration function for each existing callback function, and put each one in the same separate php files as its existing callback function. Then the main plugin file can contain `require_once` for each other php file, and the last line (which in the below example contains `rest_api_init`). Sound good?

Comment: That plan should absolutely work. I personally wouldn't prescribe any specific pattern for code organization, I'd leave that up to your preference for what makes sense. For me, I usually register my callbacks as anonymous functions that invoke PSR-4 autoloaded coded from my `src` folder, just because the API registering stuff is mostly boilerplate, but that's just my own style.

Comment: Can you use this hook in a callback function that is run from a 'plugins_loaded'  action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So register_rest_route goes inside "rest_api_init" action hook, and callbacks for routes can be defined in same file or in external one (then you can require it inside main file so you could add them to route/s). Here's an example:

Let's say you have a plugin "api-test", it's placed in: \wp-content\plugins\api-test and we'll add api-test.php as main plugin file (will be functional not oop for this example sake). Inside api-test.php you can have something like:

```
/**
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name: WP Rest api testing..
 */

/**
 * at_rest_testing_endpoint
 * @return WP_REST_Response
 */
function at_rest_testing_endpoint()
{
    return new WP_REST_Response('Howdy!!');
}

/**
 * at_rest_init
 */
function at_rest_init()
{
    // route url: domain.com/wp-json/$namespace/$route
    $namespace = 'api-test/v1';
    $route     = 'testing';

    register_rest_route($namespace, $route, array(
        'methods'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback'  => 'at_rest_testing_endpoint'
    ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'at_rest_init');
```

This is really simple example where everything's in the same file.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyTee, I will test and report back here. I plan to move the two example functions `at_rest_testing_endpoint` and `at_rest_init` to a seperate PHP file and then `require_once` that file here.

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked. For posterity, I then modified/ehanced by splitting into functional files (each `require`d in the main plugin file), added a `'permission_callback' => '__return_true',` to avoid the WP soft error in v5.5+ (my functions are for all site visitors so that auth is fine in my use case), and wrapped all the functions in class structures.

Comment: what should an example URL look like to get  '`Howdy !!`'  displayed in the browser? `http://localhost/wordpress/?someKey=someValue` dont work in my tests

Comment: @SL5net Use the following url ``https://example.com/wp-json/$namespace/$route`` given in the commentary (replacing namespace and route of course)