# WordPress endpoint plugin shows SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Tags: wordpress, endpoint

i have read many pages to find out howto create a simple endpoint into my simple WP-Plugin.

#### links of good articles i have read for that:

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/plugin-api-extension/ , https://wptips.dev/custom-rest-api/ , https://torquemag.io/2016/07/adding-custom-endpoints-extra-touches/ , https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-rest-api-to-fetch-posts/#get-wp-v2-posts , https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-rest-api-to-fetch-posts/#wordpress-rest-api-using-json , https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

#### this gives me most hope to get success with it and i used the source from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64331655/2891692

#### My URL i using in Web-Browser:

`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/a0plugin/v1/testing`

#### excerpt of my complete source from gist

htdocs/wp-content/plugins/a0plugin/a0plugin.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:         a0plugin
 */
function at_rest_testing_endpoint(){
    return new WP_REST_Response('Howdy!!');
}
function at_rest_init(){
    $namespace = 'a0plugin/v1';
    $route     = 'testing';
    register_rest_route($namespace, $route, array(
        'methods'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback'  => 'at_rest_testing_endpoint'
    ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'at_rest_init');
?>
```

complete source:

https://gist.github.com/sl5net/10d21e8bd358b9149968885a93862424

#### SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the comments are left out, the error disappears. these are not listed in the so-called relevant source text excerpt. the cause is unknown to me.